# Adding scroll view to an EditText in Android

Tags: android, xamarin, android-edittext, android-scrollbar

Here's a sample layout:

[image: Sample Layout]

so... The edit text that you see at the bottom most part of the screen has a match_parent attributes on both its layout_height and width.

The max allowed characters are 200, but if the user hits 'enter' a lot of times, the overall vertical length increases. When it goes beyond the scope, it should show a scrollbar if you scroll on the edit text.

Right now, the text scrolls but the scroll bar is absent. :[

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: By scroll bar, i only mean only the visual indicator. The types you see on a lisview which you can't really hold and scroll, but just indicates how long the list is.

Comment: might be helpful to share your code, so someone can try it.

Comment: Have u added this line in your EditText Xml code : 
android:scrollbars="vertical"